# Canonical posts

Tags: discussion, canonical-posts

**Canonical posts -> CP**

---

I think the active users or users who are good at english should make more CP's in my opinion, so we can cite them for duplicates.

I understand that it can be extremely time consuming to make a CP, but I also do not want to look away from the immense benefits of a CP. Stoney-B's CP helped many people, and reached over 175k people! His effort put into the massive CP really inspired me!

> I feel if we can get this one right, a lot of current and future questions on the passive could be closed as duplicates. - @FumbleFingers on passive voice CP

I really hope that making more CP's will allow us to close duplicates and help users more easily with CP's.

So if you guys have any ideas for any more future CP's, please add on the community wiki answer below.

If it is a new idea, please make it:

> Name [Proposal stage (incomplete)]

If it is an idea and people think it is a good idea, change it to:

> Name [Proposal stage (accepted - incomplete)]

If it is a new idea with no reconigition on ELL.meta yet.

Additionally please ask a question on meta regarding your idea on it for othet to "judge" it, and place the link in the community wiki below your CP proposal name.

### List of Canonical posts:

- [**Meta** - Introducing canonical posts](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/754/introducing-canonical-posts)
- [Canonical post 1 - When to trust your grammar checker](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8743/canonical-post-1-when-to-trust-your-grammar-checker)
- [**Meta** - Proposal for Canonical post 2 on perfect constructions](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/724/canonical-post-for-perfect-constructions?rq=1)
- [Canonical post 2 - What is the perfect and how should I use it](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it)
- [**Meta** - Canonical post on passive voice - **Incomplete**](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2684/call-for-volunteers-in-search-of-a-canonical-post-on-passive-voice?rq=1)
- [**Meta** - Question about Canonical posts](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5700/canonical-posts-idea)

---

I want to bring back CP, but I am not sure if all of this is neccessary or not. Please let me know.

Comment: I think you're underestimating just how time consuming and difficult this project is. Writing a detailed, *and* accurate canonical post takes considerable *time*, *effort* –just think the amount of research  StoneyB must have done beforehand–I believe he did this alone, and he did a marvellous job. But most of all, anyone who takes on this endeavor must be a highly competent speaker, writer and communicator. In other words, someone *really* good at English and have the free time and passion to undertake this thankless task. There are very **very few**
 users who I feel could accomplish it.

Comment: I meant to advertise for more CP to be made, but not for them to be posted within the first day @Mari-LouA

Comment: And it looked like Stoney B wrote it entirely by himself, I don't see any sources. @Mari-LouA. Wendikidd's first CP didnt take long to write either

Comment: How long do you think it took Wendikidd to write up that post? Why don't you start rolling the ball by writing a post explaining how learners can construct the passive, when to use it, and when it is entirely unnecessary. Explain why not every active sentence can be transformed into the passive voice. Don't forget to include the negative and interrogative forms, and the different tenses. Post it on meta so users can critique and refine it if need be.

Comment: Just to give you an idea why nobody is volunteering to compose a CP, think how complicated it would get if we attempted to write guidelines about:  **will** (We will go to the park later) , **be going to** (We're going to go to the park later ), **present continuous** (We're going to the park later), **present perfect future** (We'll have gone to the park) and the **simple present** (Biden goes to the park).

Comment: So you're suggesting I should try making one for passive? (I wish to make a CP, but not sure where to start and that my english is not even good) plus, I am allowed to use multiple sources on a CP @Mari-LouA. Thanks

Comment: Where does it say "I am allowed to use multiple sources on a CP"? Where? Obviously if it's just going to be a copy and paste job and if the post is filled with links, then no, it's not a "canonical answer" (as I understand it). It's a post with references. But I don't see anything bad in an answer that cites its sources.

Comment: I would leave this post up. One person disagreeing with the idea is nothing.

Answer (score 2):

### Future Canonical posts:

- Passive voice [Proposal stage (accepted - incomplete)]

  [**Meta** - Canonical post 3 - Passive voice](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2684/call-for-volunteers-in-search-of-a-canonical-post-on-passive-voice?rq=1)

  Proposed by @WendiKidd
- Tense and Aspect [Proposal stage (incomplete)]
  [Would it be helpful to have a canonical post on Tense and Aspect? [Proposal stage (incomplete)]](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5923/would-it-be-helpful-to-have-a-canonical-post-on-tense-and-aspect-proposal-stag)

### Complete Canonical posts:

- When to trust your grammar checker

  [Canonical post 1 - When to trust your grammar checker](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8743/canonical-post-1-when-to-trust-your-grammar-checker)

  Proposed by @WendiKidd
- What is the perfect and how should I use it

  [**Meta** - Canonical post 2 - perfect constructions](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/724/canonical-post-for-perfect-constructions?rq=1)

  [Canonical post 2 - What is the perfect and how should I use it](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it)

  Proposed by @WendiKidd