# Would it be helpful to have a canonical post on Tense and Aspect? [Proposal stage (incomplete)]

Tags: discussion, canonical-posts

**Status Update:** Upon discussion with an experienced member of the community who is currently teaching English, I have come to the conclusion that it may not be possible to present any single system of classifying the tenses as being a "basic" or "standard" model.

There seems to be a lack of consensus on having a definitive system even at the elementary school/new ESL learner level, not just among linguistics scholars. Supporting this observation: http://random-idea-english.blogspot.com/2014/01/a-brief-history-of-tense.html

Given this consideration, <s>I'm considering abandoning this topic for a Canonical Post as "inherently opinion based," and closing this Meta question.</s>I have voted to close this question as "Opinion-Based."

Reason: It wouldn't be correct to present any one model as being definitive/universal if it *isn't*, but the alternative would be a discussion and comparison among many different models (along the lines of the original CP proposal before editing). This was considered to be not a good fit for this site.

<s>I'm only waiting for a final verdict from one of the other contributors before close-voting this.</s>

Thank you to everyone who has invested their time and attention in this discussion. I would be open to contributing to the CP project on a different topic if an alternative is proposed by the community.

---

Edit: **This has been significantly revised** - see the edit history and the discussion in the comments. Instead of an overview and comparison of the different models in use to describe the tense system in English, the focus has been shifted to explaining the details of the most basic model. In its original form, this CP proposal was thought to be too opinion-based or likely to generate off-topic discussion.

**PROPOSED CANONICAL POST - SUGGESTIONS FOR IMPROVEMENT ARE WELCOME!**

---

**TENSE AND ASPECT**

- **What tenses exist in English? How many are there?**

That depends on how you define **tense**! For now, let's stick with the simplest definition.  This is the one most native speakers learn in school, and also the one you are most likely to see if you're new to learning English. **Tense** is defined by the Merriam-Webster online dictionary as "[a distinction of form in a verb to express distinctions of time or duration of the action or state it denotes](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tense)."

First, let's look at the "distinctions of form" which "express distinctions of time."  Using "categorize" as an example, here are each of the **6 distinct tenses** that exist in English:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Present | They categorize |
| Past | They categorized |
| Future | They will categorize* |
| (Present) Perfect | They have categorized |
| Past Perfect [also called Pluperfect] | They had categorized |
| Future Perfect | They will have categorized |

[This post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-and-aspects-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-an?noredirect=1&lq=1) on ELU has a helpful chart showing how the different tenses fit into the timeline.

*Adding the helping verb "will" is the most basic way of indicating the future tense.  *In actual conversation*, however, you're *as likely or more likely* to hear future actions described with a construction like "going to categorize" or "about to categorize" instead of "will categorize." Sometimes, just the present continuous on its own can be used to refer to the future, when the meaning is clear from the context. You can see some examples of this here: [How to say that you have plans to go to the movies tonight?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/76641/how-to-say-that-you-have-plans-to-go-to-the-movies-tonight) and here: [When to use "be going to" / present continuous in future?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56094/when-to-use-be-going-to-present-continuous-in-future?noredirect=1&lq=1)

---

- **What is "aspect"?**

Each *tense* has 2 variants--the **Simple** and the **Progressive/Continuous**--which are called *aspects*.

The characteristic of **aspect** *adds more detail* to the time information given by the **tense**: information about "the duration of the action or state" the verb "denotes."

The word "tense" is sometimes used to describe *the combination of a tense plus an aspect*.  For example, you might hear about the "Simple Present Tense" or the "Past Continuous Tense."

Combining the two aspects with the six tenses listed above gives a total of **12** different possibilities.**  This time, we'll demonstrate these with the verb "sit," because it has fewer letters:

|  | Simple | Continuous |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Present | They sit | They are sitting |
| Past | They sat | They were sitting |
| Future | They will sit | They will be sitting |
| Perfect | They have sat | They have been sitting |
| Past Perfect | They had sat | They had been sitting |
| Future Perfect | They will have sat | They will have been sitting |

**Sometimes you'll hear about there being **12** tenses in English, instead of 6.  If your teacher or textbook talks about the 12 tenses, they are most likely referring to the 12 combinations of **tense and aspect**.

---

- **What about tense and aspect for non-finite forms?**

Non-finite forms (the infinitive, participle, and gerund) also have *tense* and *aspect*, but they only have **two** different possibilities for tense (*present* and *perfect*) instead of the six that finite verbs have.

|  | Simple Present | Present Continuous | Simple Perfect | Perfect Continuous |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Infinitive | to sit | to be sitting | to have sat | to have been sitting |
| Participle | N/A | sitting | having sat | having been sitting |
| Gerund | N/A | sitting | having sat | having been sitting |

What tense to use for the non-finite forms is determined by their time reference relative to the main verb in the sentence.

- If the action of the non-finite form happens *at the same time* as that of the main verb, use a **present** form:

  - "Alice is known to like apples and oranges." *The time reference of the action described by the infinitive "to like" is the same as that of the main verb "is known": both present.*
  - "Sitting on the bench, Bob saw a seagull." *Bob's seeing the seagull happens at the same time as his sitting - both in the past.*
  - "Rover's barking at a squirrel startled the seagull." *The main verb "startled" is in the simple past tense. The dog's barking coincides with the seagull being startled (i.e. the two actions happen in the same timeframe), so even though the sentence describes cause and effect, the tense of "barking" should be present, not perfect.*
- If the action of the non-finite form happens *before* that of the main verb, use a **perfect** form:

  - "Carol is known to have been baking cupcakes all morning for the fundraiser." *The time reference of the action described by the infinitive "to have been baking" is earlier than that of the main verb "is known": the action of "baking" happened in the past, while "is known" refers to the present. Note the use of a continuous aspect for the perfect infinitive, as it describes an action occurring over a period of time.*
  - "Having sat on the bench, Dan knows it's uncomfortable." *The action indicated by "having sat" happened sometime in the past, while the main verb "knows" refers to the present time.*
  - "Evan will arrive at school late due to having overslept." *"Having overslept" refers to an action in the past, while "will arrive" refers to the future, so the gerund is perfect tense in this  sentence.*

Comment: I'll keep on adding links to the Potentially Helpful Questions section as I find them.  The intent is to have a gallery of good reference Q/A pairs, like the one in Part 5 of StoneyB's canonical post here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Also currently unsure as to whether I should add a section on Sequence under the Non-Finite Forms section.  Any opinions on whether this would be relevant here, or an unnecessary tangent?  By "sequence," I'm referring to the rule for determining the non-finite form's tense relative to the main verb.

Comment: We already have a CP about perfect. Would this supersede that one? Would it greatly overlap it? Why not continue the pattern we already have and create a separate CP about each individual tense and aspect?

Comment: @gotube The primary intent behind this post was to have a "disambiguation" page that would give an overview of each of the (two?) main models for understanding tense and aspect.  In order to avoid confusion from askers getting answers which appear to contradict each other - this would clarify that there are different approaches with different pros and cons.  Following the model of the CP about the Perfect (which I have read; it's a truly impressive project by StoneyB :D), I thought it might be helpful to also include a list of good Qs and As for each of the different tenses.

Comment: @gotube This isn't intended to overlap with CP#2 at all, except as far as the perfect is a tense (or aspect, depending on your perspective) and so should be included in the tables.  It's more of a meta-discussion I guess: it isn't about *a* tense or aspect so much as about *ways of considering* tense and aspect

Comment: @gotube "Why not continue the pattern we already have and create a separate CP about each individual tense and aspect?" -- I'm not sure if that was meant literally or rhetorically? If you're saying that what I was going for in the rough outline seems too broad or unfocused, then I will attempt to refine it to stick to a narrower scope (as defined in my first comment under yours).  If that was an actual suggestion, *wow* that would be a big project!  But, I'll volunteer to start on *one* (which one?), although I doubt it will compare to the existing one on the Perfect

Comment: By "the two main models", do you mean the ESL/EFL model and the Linguistics model? If so, I agree it is a problem worth fixing, but I'm not convinced the Linguistics model is really worth giving any special prominence -- and this is coming from a Linguistics major. I've taught English for nearly 20 years now, and in almost every place where the ESL world and academic Linguistics differ, the ESL way is significantly better for learners, which stands to reason as it's an industry based on what works to help learners learn, not what's verifiable with enough data and philosophical argumentation.

Comment: How long do you intend this CP to be relative to the material you already have there? Is this about it, or double or 10x the length? If your intent was to stay closer to the current length rather than, say, 10x as long, then disregard my question about a separate CP for each individual thing. As this was just a proposal, I couldn't tell the scope of your intent, but I've probably gleaned it from your answer here.

Comment: @gotube I don't intend it to be *significantly* longer than it is now: more like double (or not even that) and definitely not 10x! Mostly I was hoping someone more technically knowledgeable might help out with the last section. I was also considering adding a section on Sequence of Tenses as it relates to non-finite forms (like the infinitive) having their tense determined by their relation to the main verb's time reference (and also for the subjunctive)

Comment: Primarily, if the community agrees that the idea would be helpful, I was just looking for suggestions for improvements to what's there, and was planning on "polishing" the rough draft (for one thing, I'll be fixing that numbering mistake in the superscripts!  Also "10 = 12" has to go).

Comment: Am I right about your intent of EFL-based answers vs Linguistics-based answers?

Comment: @gotube I'm not clear on your last question?  If you mean that I tend to answer questions from non-native speakers, and that I don't have a linguistics background, those are both true.  Also, I intend this proposed CP to be mainly a resource for EFL learners.  It would probably seem like stating the obvious to anyone who *does* have significant linguistics knowledge.

Comment: If your main intent is *to have a "disambiguation" page that would give an overview of each of the (two?) main models for understanding tense and aspect*, then I think that this is too long and detailed. I recommend starting small, since it can always be expanded if needed. (Keep in mind that if it gains traction, then others may also want to contribute, and it can quickly spiral into something big and unwieldy.)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan That is a good point, but what should get cut?  Do you think the list of links is out of place in this kind of post?

Comment: I don't know because, like @gotube, I'm unsure of the main purpose: What are "the (two?) main models for understanding tense and aspect"?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan #1 - The 6-tense, 3-variant model, which I have described (thoroughly?) in the first section.  #2 - This I'm less clear on, but there seems to be a consensus from scholarly sources on a 2-tense system (how many aspects? I'm not sure).

Comment: In System 1, non-finite forms also have tense and aspect. In System 2, I believe they would say that they don't.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Yes, system #2 claims that English has only two tenses, present and past, since those are the only finite forms that verbs take. In that case, you don't need to describe things like future perfect continuous, for example. Just mention the two systems, describe them briefly, and save the "implementation details" for other canonical posts (like StoneyB's).

Comment: Getting into different models opens the floodgates for proponents of any model to insist theirs gets representation. Linguistically speaking, I think the 2-tense model is the most robust, but for English learners, it makes no sense to me to name fewer than seven -- I always include "be going to" as a basic tense, in addition to the six you already have.

Comment: @gotube I would consider that to be an alternate form of the future tense: how should I label it in the table? "Future Periphrastic," maybe, as I believe that is the term for a multi-part construction.  I have also just edited the suggestion to cut all but the core concepts, and eliminated a lot of the examples and explanations.

Comment: "Getting into different models opens the floodgates for proponents of any model to insist theirs gets representation" - That could really inflate the post into something unmanageable! Should I only compare/contrast 6 tenses vs. 2, and get rid of any mention of additional systems? I'm not sure though whether it's possible to keep the "disambiguation" concept without mentioning the possibility of having multiple models.  Do you have any ideas for how to avoid this issue?

Comment: "Do you have any ideas for how to avoid this issue?" As I said in [my comment above](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5923/would-it-be-helpful-to-have-a-canonical-post-on-tense-and-aspect-proposal-stag?noredirect=1#comment15628_5923), I don't recommend presenting any modern academic Linguistic model as on equal footing with standard EFL models. IMO, they're no more valid in EFL than EFL models are valid in academic Linguistics, and they can only serve to confuse learners. So the simple way to avoid the issue is only to present EFL tense models, like the six-or-seven tenses.

Comment: The only different "model" I'd mention is that many people regularly call progressive forms "tenses", while others call them "aspects", and it doesn't matter which term is used as far as learning goes.

Comment: "Be going to"-future is not an "alternate form of the future tense". It's not a form of "will" at all. It's a present progressive structure, which by convention indicates the future, just as "will"-future is a present modal verb, which by convention indicates the future. "Be going to" is the default future tense of English, not "will". The two have no more in common with each other than simple past and present perfect do.

Comment: @gotube I'll revise the outline again tomorrow following your suggestions.  So, completely eliminate the second section, and expand the first with a discussion of how "going to" works (plus clarify the usage of *aspect* vs. *tense* for the progressive)?  That will leave the discussion of the 6 tenses, plus 2 aspects, and the emphatic forms, along with the clarification that "12 tenses" comes from conflating tense with aspect (6 * 2 = 12). I'm not sure that this CP will have much value for clarification if it doesn't address the full range of answers that learners' questions might get (contd)

Comment: but do you think it would be worth keeping as a reference on the standard system? Or scrap the proposal entirely?  Is a reference on exclusively the most common system for classifying tense and aspect really necessary, given that there are probably many online resources that already do so?

Comment: I was trying to find some examples of questions which had gotten conflicting answers from different viewpoints to serve as a reference (for the original topic of this proposal), but of course as soon as I started looking for *these specifically*, I couldn't find any.  These discussions https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/254104/how-many-verb-moods-in-english-3-4-5-or-more/254106#254106 and https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/152884/how-many-types-of-tense-are-there were the closest I could find, and do illustrate that there are some good questions and answers on this site that do

Comment: go into the kind of depth you'd expect from EL&U.

Comment: @gotube and MarcInManhattan: Edited again

Comment: Where does "emphatic aspect" come from?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Oops, if I used that phrase somewhere in my post, that was a mistake. I'm aware that "emphatic" *isn't* an "aspect," and I tried to make that clear in the explanation above the second table. I meant to only refer to "simple" and "continuous" as "aspects," but I'm not sure how to classify "emphatic" so I went with just calling it a "variant" of a tense. I'll take another look at the post and if I've written "emphatic aspect" anywhere, I'll fix that.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Where in the outline do you see that phrase? I just reread my post and couldn't find it.

Comment: Sorry, 'emphatic tense'! What would a google ngram for 'present perfect tense' and 'present emphatic tense' look like? [I've never heard of the latter]

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I'll give ngram a try and see what comes up. I thought it was a fairly common term, but may be mistaken. It certainly wouldn't do to include something idiosyncratic in a Canonical Post :D Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: results: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=present+emphatic&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3 https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=present+emphatic%2Cpresent+perfect&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3 https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=present+emphatic+tense%2Cpresent+perfect+tense&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3 It looks like it's actually very uncommon - I'm surprised!

Comment: At least one confirmed source does use the term "emphatic tense": "When the verb to do is used as a helping verb and combined with another verb, it forms what is sometimes referred to as the emphatic tense. This tense is used for emphasis, in negative statements, and in questions." - Quote taken from a book called Alpha Teach Yourself Grammar & Style in 24 Hours https://www.google.com/books/edition/Alpha_Teach_Yourself_Grammar_Style_in_24/KfnHgbENH40C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22emphatic+tense%22&pg=PA82&printsec=frontcover

Comment: Which was linked from the ngram results. So, I'm not the only one using it, but it seems as if it doesn't really compare with the "big" ones like "present perfect."  Should I remove "emphatic" entirely from the post, or consign it to a footnote?

Comment: @QuackE.Duck Well, it's really a construction rather than a tense, I think. For example, the same type of stress is used in the same way with any auxiliary verb, for example the modal verbs. I'd remove it, if it were up to me :)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Removed it - that *did* streamline things. The post flows better without the frequent tangents about emphatic forms getting in the way!

Comment: @QuackE.Duck Shall we discuss this in chat?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Sure, if you prefer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147625/discussion-between-araucaria-not-here-any-more-and-quack-e-duck).